# Array functions by id

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I want to do the work of a changing array by question number 
ex : `$array[$qssr['id']]`
For I do by placing them in loop
For example :      `foreach ($array[$qssr['id']] as &$value)`

The value of array

```
$answers1 = mysql_query("select * from answers where qid='".$qnid."' LIMIT 0, 1") or die("error");
$answersr1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($answers1);
```

My experiment failed :

```
function get_answer($qid)
{
    $answers = mysql_query("select * from answers where qid='".$qid."' LIMIT 0, 1") or die("error");
    $answersr = mysql_fetch_assoc($answers);

    $arr= array();

    foreach($answersr as $v)
    {
        $arr[] = $v['answer'];
    }
}

   $array = array();


$qss = mysql_query("select * from qs where sid='$finalsid' order by id asc") or die("error");
$qssr = mysql_fetch_assoc($qss);


    $qanswer = get_answer($qssr['id']);


    $array[$qssr['id']] = $q_answer;



foreach ($array[$qssr['id']] as &$value)
```

Comment: get_answer is useless. why `select *` only to throw away all the fields except one? then for every field in your table, you create a new array entry but stuff in only the `answer` field value, then you throw away that array without ever returning it.

Comment: how i can do it .. please can you show my example for that

Comment: `$result = mysql_query(...); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); return $row['answer']`

Comment: but how i can add all value $row['answer'] of in Array to add it in loop ex : foreach ($array[$qssr['id']] as &$value)

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Also, your variables are not even consistently named. First you use $qanswer and then you use $q_answer

Comment: i do it for example but if i named the variables the code failed !!
how i can do arrey in the loop foreach  by id with a value by id q